# Sessions with Google Cloud Endpoints [Python]

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to get a session service working with Cloud Endpoints so when my user refresh the page, they do not lose everything.

I thought I had it figure it out with gae-session : https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions as it works locally.

But for some reason when I upload my code, the session does not work. I am not sure why this is happening (SSL maybe?)

I get my session back like this

```
class MyApi(remote.Service):

  def __init__(self):
    # Retrieve session if exists
    self.session = get_current_session()

  @endpoints.method(message, message, path='app_init', http_method='POST', name='app.init')
  def AppInit(self, request):
    if not self.session.is_active():
      logging.info('session active')
    else:
      logging.info('no active session)
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong or maybe a better solution?

Thanks